# ネットワーク構築を具体的に知りたい

Tags: network

ネットワーク構築を具体的に知りたい
以前にネットワークエンジニアの人と話したときに聞いたのですが、
コンピュータ同士をネットワークでつながった、つながらない、を繰り返してつなげるだけです
と言われました。

このスタックオーバーフローを通して、つなげ方が聞きたいわけではなく、このコンピュータとこのコンピュータはつなげて、別のこれらのコンピュータ同士はつなげないみたいな状況の具体的な状況ってどういう状況なのですか？

別の質問の仕方をすると、
あるネットワーク環境の構築にしたいという目的があって、その目的のためにネットワーク設計があって、そのネットワーク設計に従ってネットワークを構築していくと思うのですが、あるネットワーク環境の構築の具体的な例を経験のある方にお尋ねしたいです。

ネットワーク構築の経験がないので経験がある方の今までにあった具体的な状況をおたずねしたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 何が聞きたいのかわかりませんが、ここに書き込めているということは、インターネットに接続できているということで、「ネットワーク構築の経験」はあるのでは？

Comment: @WebSurfer 今時スマホを買って携帯電話会社と契約すれば誰でもインターネットに接続できます。また、学校・会社やネカフェに行けばインターネットに繋がったパソコンを利用できます。そのような人達もここに書き込めますが、それをもって「ネットワーク構築の経験」があるとするのは、いささか乱暴な理論ではありませんか？

Comment: 「具体的に知りたい」とありますが、ここで一から十まで説明するには範囲が広すぎる気がします。例えば Amazon 等で「ネットワークのしくみ」をキーワードに検索すると複数の書籍が見つかるので、まずはそれらを参考にしてみてはいかがでしょうか？ある程度学習を進めた上で **分からないことを具体的に** 絞り込んでもらった上で質問してもらった方が回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ネットワーク構築する具体的な状況が知りたかっただけなのですが、それでも範囲が広いでしょうか？

想像ですが、例えばお客さんからこのパソコンからネットワークをつなげて、また別のパソコンからネットワークをつなげないといった状況があるのではないかと思います。

Comment: @raccy あなたに聞いているわけではなく質問者さんに聞いてます。質問者さんの答えに応じて回答するつもりです。なのでそういう横レスは不要です。

Comment: @WebSurfer 単に、質問を読んでも質問者に「ネットワーク構築の経験」があるかないかわからなかったと言うことですね。質問の最後の文で「ネットワーク構築の経験がない」と明記されていますので、「ネットワーク構築の経験」は無いと判断していいかと思います。

Comment: @webSurfer
質問の言い方を変えます。世の中のネットワーク設計者はお客さんにこんなネットワーク環境を構築してほしいといわれたことがあると思います。
そのネットワーク環境は具体的にいままででよくある例でもかまいませんが
どんなネットワーク環境を構築したかざっくりでいいので教えてほしいということです。

Comment: @raccy あなたの横レスはいらないと言っているのですが。

Comment: @japan 「ネットワーク構築の経験」はあるのでは？・・・に答えてもらえませんか？　あなたに経験があるならどういうネットワークなのかも。また、あなたの聞きたい「ネットワーク」が対象とするのは何なのか書いてください。一般家庭内の LAN？　大規模な企業内ネットワーク？　その他だったら何？

Comment: @WebSurfer ネットワークエンジニアが少なくともお客さんから依頼される程度のネットワークを対象としています。

Comment: @japan 「お客さんから依頼される」ネットワーク構築の実例の紹介ですか？　それは自分にはできませんので、すみませんが、撤退します。他の方の回答をお待ちください。

Comment: @websurfer そうです

Answer (score 3):

なぜ、ネットワークと言う物が必要なのかがわからないという事でしょうか？単にインターネットに接続したいだけなら、5G/LTE搭載ノートPCだけで事足りますし、サーバーもパブリッククラウドを使えば良いので、現代的なシステムではネットワークはもう不要かも知れません。それでも、ルーターやファイアウォールやスイッチングハブや無線アクセスポイント等を使ってネットワークを構築している組織は多いです。なぜ、そのような必要があるのかの具体例を挙げていきます。

#### なるべく安価に複数台のパソコンで安全にインターネットに接続したい。

インターネットに接続するだけなら、全てのパソコンで5G/LTE搭載ノートパソコンにすれば良いだけです。安全性は個々に強力なセキュリティソフトを買えば良いでしょう。ただこの場合は、パソコン一台毎にインターネット接続回線の契約が必要です。数台程度なら良いですが、数百台、数千台となると回線費用やセキュリティソフトの費用が現実的ではありません。

インターネット回線はルーターの一つだけにして、他のパソコンはスイッチハブや無線アクセスポイントからルーターに接続して、インターネットに接続する方が費用がとても安価になります。安全性のためにはUTM(ファイアウォール、IPS/IDS、アンチウイルス等の機能を統合した機器)を入れて置けばよく、個々のパソコンに入れるよりも手間が少なく確実な動作を保証できます。

これは、組織だけでは無く、家庭でもよく行われます。いわゆるブロードバンドルーターと言われるものはルーターにスイッチングハブと無線アクセスポイントの機能があわさっており、数台程度であれば、その一台だけでお手軽にネットワークを構築できます。また、Wi-Fiルーターやホームルーターも電源を入れるだけでこの構成ができるようになっています。つまり、知らず知らず、だれもが構築したことがあると言うことです。ただ、家庭向け製品は、デフォルトの設定でも簡単に構築できるようになっているため、そのことを意識している人は少ないかも知れません。

#### オンプレミスのサーバーを通信させたい。

サーバーというのは、パソコンなどに何らかのサービスを提供するものです。現代的なシステムではパブリッククラウドを使えばよく、サーバーを組織内に置く必要は必ずしもありません。しかし、何らかの理由(組織内部の規定とか、法的問題とか、セキュリティ上の懸念とか、価格とか)で、組織内に置かなければならない場合があります。組織内におくことをオンプレミスといいます。

オンプレミスのサーバーであっても、パソコンから使えなければ意味がありません。パソコンの話と同じように、5G/LTEモデムを繋げてしまうという手もありますが、セキュリティ上の理由で、内部からの通信はインターネットを経由しない」とか「インターネットからの通信は高度なセキュリティで保護する」とかの要件があると難しいです。内部からの通信だけが必要というのであれば、内部のスイッチングハブに繋いだ方が早いです。インターネットからの通信はUTMで保護するなどの設定が必要でしょう。サーバーの用途によってどこのどのように置くのかは異なりますが、オンプレミスのサーバーを置くという段階で、何らかのセットワーク構成を考える必要はでてきます。

#### ネットワークを分割したり、結合したりしたい。

ひとまず、複数台のパソコンやサーバーのためにルーター、UTM、スイッチングハブ、無線アクセスポイント等をつかって、内部での通信とインターネットの通信はできるようになったとしましょう。ただ、実際のネットワークはもっと複雑です。なぜなら、状況に応じてネットワークの分割や結合が生じるからです。例えば、次のような事例です。

1. ブロードキャストストーム等の発生を防ぐために、ブロードキャストドメイン(ネットワーク)を分ける。
   一つのネットワークに、IPアドレスとしては10.0.0.0/8を使えば16777214個までパソコンなどを置けますが、これは現実的ではありません。一つのネットワークに接続されたパソコンが多くなるとブロードキャストが多数発生して、全体の通信が遅くなる恐れがあります。さらに、リピーターハブという大昔の装置を使っていた時代は、コリジョンという問題が発生しやすくなるため、特に深刻でした。そのため、ある程度規模が大きい組織では、ルーターやレイヤー3スイッチングハブで複数のネットワークに分割しています。
2. ネットワーク間のアクセス制限を設ける。
   ネットワークを分割する理由は通信が遅くなるだけではありません。ネットワーク間でアクセス制限などができるようになるからです。よくあるのは、ファイアウァールでWAN(インターネットに直接繋がっているネットワーク)、DMZ(インターネットと通信することがあるサーバーなどを置くネットワーク)、LAN(その他のパソコンやサーバーなど、インターネットへはDMZ内にあるプロキシサーバーなどを使用しする)とわける場合でしょう。それぞれの間の通信を必要最低限にすることで、インターネットからの攻撃からLANにあるパソコンを守ることができます。
   その他、L3スイッチングハブで簡易のACLを使って他部署間の通信を制限するなどを行っている場合もあります。
3. 他の拠点とネットワークを繋ぐ。
   地理的に離れた場所にあるパソコン同士で通信したい場合はどうしたら良いのでしょうか？光ケーブルを埋設して(または借りて)繋ぐという手もありますが、距離が大きすぎる場合はかなり高額な費用になります。かといって、単純にインターネットを経由した通信ではセキュリティ的に不安です。
   そういうときに使われるのがVPNです。やりかたやVPNの種類がたくさんあるため一概に言えませんが、これは本来わかれたネットワークを仮想的に繋ぐという仕組みです。

これらはほんの一例です。各機器を冗長化したい、インターネット回線のバックアップを置きたい、Wi-Fiに認証機能を設けたい、等々、要件が増えていく毎に複雑になってきます。組織の規模によっても、家庭向けに毛が生えた程度のSOHO向けブロードバンドルーター1台でのみで済んでいたものから、数千万円もコアスイッチやUTM、多数のフロアスイッチと無線アクセスポイント等を用いて大規模かつ複雑なものまで様々です。より具体例が知りたいというのであれば、より要件を絞らないと、示すのは難しいと思います。